# Getting Apache to be able to write to a folder

Tags: apache2

I've been tinkering with Apache2 in Ubuntu and am trying to get a script of mine to be able to create files. It doesn't seem to be working, sadly. I think the issue is that whichever user is running doesn't have the right permission to create files. I've been going round in circles with this, though - I thought I had set the permissions for the `/var/www` (it's testing only so I'm not worried about security) to `777`. Still no luck.

Is there anything I'm missing?

I've tried: adding my main user to the `www-data` user group; setting `www-data` as owning the `/var/www` folder, and lots of other attempts besides.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make a folder inside `/var/www/` putting your script in that and running it from there.  Making sure to do `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/test` before hand?

Seems strange it won't do it even with the permissions set to 777.  Is it a PHP script you are playing with?

Maybe try the following:

```
$ cd /var/www
$ php -a
php> file_put_contents('test','test');
php> exit
$ cat test
```

And see if it outputs the file.  If that works, paste `<?php file_put_contents('test','test'); ?>` into a file and run it, see if it does the same thing.

If it outputs the file too, then it must be a problem with your script.